# Why don't all washing machines beep when finished?

Tags: household

I've owned several dishwashers, and they all beep loudly several times when they have finished a cycle. Not that I care, because I don't need to rush to open them and grab the clean plates. Usually it beeps at 3am and I sleep through the noise.

But when my clothes finish cleaning, I *do* need to rush to open the washing machine straight away, because everything gets creased otherwise. I want to hang it up quick! Yet no washing machine I've ever owned has beeped when it finishes a cycle. Apparently they exist, as some people have posted below. **But why not all of them?**

It is true that I am alerted to the approximate time a cycle ends, because of the loud noise of the spinning drum. But I haven't memorised the length of this period, it can vary in duration, and I get distracted every time by what I am doing. The silence when the spinning ends is not a noticeable event which makes me realise the cycle might be over. Anyway, there are several periods of spin/quiet/spin/quiet.

So why don't all laundry appliances beep? The electrical components to achieve this cannot cost more than 1GBP. The machine's microcontroller already knows when the cycle ends as it has to begin a door-unlock timer, and change the LEDs displayed. It seems crazy they don't beep.

Comment: There are washing machines which do beep : http://ppsanil.blogspot.in/2012/01/siemens-washing-machine-kill-buzzer.html

Comment: Mine does beep ;)

Comment: It might be worth making this question a bit more generic: ie 'what's the best way to alert that a washing machine has finished its cycle' ?   My girlfriend's washing machine does beep and it drives me nuts as I want to be able to pause the beeping when I'm in her house - and then turn it back on to alert her later for when she comes back in as she's fussy about hanging stuff out :-)

Comment: Possibly a more interesting question is 'how do you design a dishwasher to indicate that its full of dirty not clean dishes...?' ( to avoid the 'Oh I forgot to run the dishwasher', situation )

Comment: I've owned 4 washing machines in my time, and used those belonging to 3 sets of parents, plus those of friends. Never heard a beep once in 30 years. Only time I saw mention of an audible alert was on a 'hacker's website, who had constructed a homemade electronic circuit to detect cycle end via the LEDs on the machine's front panel.

Comment: Are we talking top loaders or front loaders here? Most washing machines with a see-through door release its lock with a very audible and characteristic click upon finishing their job. Anyway, I guess the next generation of washing machines will notify your home automation framework which then pushes an announcement to the mobile devices of nearby able household members.

Comment: My washing machine beeps and it drives me nuts. I cannot find a way to turn it off!

Comment: I'm voting to close. The lack of beeping is clearly not an industry-wide design pattern. Some manufacturers seem to have worse product managers & designers than others.

Comment: Why doesn't the washer send me an email or text when the cycle is done? That would be better than a beep.

Comment: I've update my question to ask why don't ALL washing machines beep? That is a fact, not opinion. I still cant see a reason to omit this feature. (And not all machines make an audible click.)

Comment: that is a  very good idea Harvey. Wonder if any launderettes have tried it.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting the different locations and usage where dishwashers and washing machines are installed:

Dishwashers are put in kitchens where people generally are: so my observation is they do a short discrete bleep to indicate that they've finished.   There's also no need to do any follow up action as you can take the plates out and directly reuse them.

Washing machines however can be parked away in laundry rooms and garages - so they either have to 'shout loudly', or not be heard at all.   Washing machines also have a 'follow up action' - ie the user needs to notice they've finished as stuff needs putting out to dry.

Possibly one reason why washing machines haven't had the bleep historically is because ***there is the need*** for the 'follow up action' so users tend to remember to keep an eye on them in the first place.  ( I always leave the soap powder out on the worktop to remind myself to check the washing machine ).

One design feature of a washing machine bleep then would be some user control on the volume and duration of the bleep: so that users can set it loud and long if its in a washroom or quite and short if its installed in a kitchen.

Comment: I'm curious, where abouts are you?
In Europe generally washing machines are in kitchens.
Though in Japan they tend to be in bathrooms (or outside!)
I've never come across someone with a washing machine in the garage and specialist laundry rooms (meaning a single room in the house, not a room for a block of flats) are very rare

Comment: @phillipW excellent point! May washing machine tucked away in the utility area does beep, but I have to be right next to it to hear it!

Comment: In the UK.  Washing machines in the UK sometimes end up in utility rooms (or sometimes garages!) as they don't need to be in the kitchen area.  (Traditionally the UK has favoured small terraced houses rather than flats in apartment blocks).

Comment: huh, interesting. I'm British too. In my experience except in very large houses I've always seen them in kitchens.

Comment: In the Uk I've seen quite a lot in suburban houses in the garage particularly the integral garages in 70s and 80s housing which had small kitchens (no-one actually puts cars in them !)

Answer (score 0):

They do.

You seem to have owned unusual washing machines! :p

I've never had a dishwasher to comment on the comparison but certainly I have never (that I remember) used a washing machine that doesn't beep when it is done. Its quite standard.

I can only guess that with yours they figured the sound of the spinning ending and of the door popping open would be enough to alert the user that things are done. Which doesn't sound like  a wise assumption to me.

Comment: My dishwasher doesn't bleep when finished. It's all down to model preference.

Comment: Could it be a UK thing? Where abouts are you, [the other one]?

Comment: I'm British but I've lived in several different countries in Europe and in Japan. All had beeping machines. Even in laundry rooms with multiple machines and where residents usually leave the machine to do its job alone and come back 10 minutes after it is done they beep.

Wonder if there's a certain manufacturer which doesn't use beeps. I am genuinely surprised by the assumption in the original question.